# Transition CSS dropdown menu weird behaviour

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, transition

So, I'm doing a dropdown menu in CSS and I have this problem that when you mouseover the dropdown menu (features) and then mouseout it kind of glitches and jump. [Here's the pen](http://codepen.io/tyrellrummage/pen/ALvAEm) and here's the code:

```css
.cb{ width: 90%; margin: 0 auto; max-width: 1200px;}

a{
 color: inherit;
 text-decoration: inherit;
}

body{
  background: #000;
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed';
  font-weight: 300;
}

header{
 height: 100px;
 width: 100%;
 background: #fff;
 position: relative;
}

.logo{
 float: left;
 margin-top: 30px;
}

header nav{
 float: right;
 height: 100px;
}

header nav > ul{
 height: 100px;
  padding: 0;
}

header nav > ul > li{
 height: 100px;
 line-height: 100px;
 display: inline-block;
 list-style: none;
}

header nav > ul > li > a{
 height: 100px;
 display: block;
 padding: 0 30px;
 transition: all .22s;
}

header nav > ul > li > a:hover{
 color: #F78819;
}

header nav > ul > li > a:hover:after{
 transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.dropdown_icon{
 position: relative;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown_icon:after{
 position: absolute;
 display: block;
 font-family: 'FontAwesome';
 font-weight: 400;
 content: "\f107";
 top: -1px;
 font-size: 14px;
 right: 14px;
 transition: transform .22s;
}

.dropdown_item:hover ul{
  transform: scaleY(1);
}

header nav ul li ul{
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 transform: scaleY(0);
 transform-origin: 50% 0%;
 background: #F78819;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 top: 100%;
 text-align: center;
 height: 50px;
 transition: all .3s;
}

header nav ul li ul li{
 display: inline-block;
 height: 50px;
 line-height: 50px;
 vertical-align: 50px;
}

header nav ul li ul li a{
 color: #fff;
 height: 50px;
 transition: all .22s;
 display: block;
 padding: 0 20px;
}

header nav ul li ul li a:hover{
 color: #444;
}
```

```html
<header>
 <div class="cb">
  <div class="logo">
   <a href="#">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/62/Amazon.com-Logo.svg/200px-Amazon.com-Logo.svg.png" alt="Logotipo">
   </a>
  </div>

  <nav>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#" class="active">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">ABOUT US</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">SERVICES</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown_item">
     <a class="dropdown_icon">FEATURES</a>

     <ul>
      <li><a href="#">FEATURE 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">FEATURE 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">FEATURE 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">FEATURE 4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">FEATURE 5</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">FEATURE 6</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
   </ul>
  </nav>


 </div>
</header>
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: Is it because of the scrollbar that's being added, it moves to the left? You can avoid this by defining: html { overflow-y: scroll; }

Comment: It didn't have scrollbar but even with scrollbar it keeps jumping around :(

Comment: Works 100% fine for me iOS - Chrome, FF & Safari

Comment: @PsCreative I don't see any issue, maybe conflicting with other css/js. What browser are you using?

Comment: I'm getting it on Opera and Chrome at Windows. Maybe it's a webkit glitch?

Comment: @PsCreativve I am having no issues here with my Chrome on Windows.

Comment: I don't have any issues either on Chrome or Opera. Must be a conflict with the rest of the css I think...